# System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: The operation has timed out / Unable to connect server

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, smtp, timeout

The following code is mine and works in my machine (Windows 7):

```
var fromAddress = "pxx@company.com";
var toAddress = "pyyyj@company.com";
const string fromPassword = "dfdfdf";
string subject = "Test Mail Please ignore";
string body = "Test";
body += "Email: ";
body += "Subject: ";
body += "Question:";
var smtp = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient();
smtp.Host = "QAsmtp.company.net";
smtp.Port = 25;
//'smtp.EnableSsl = true;
smtp.DeliveryMethod = System.Net.Mail.SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("csweb123lab", fromPassword);
smtp.Timeout = 300000;
smtp.Send(fromAddress, toAddress, subject, body);
```

I copied this code and run into my remote machine `Windows 2008 R2 SP1` (64bit) that is also in the company network.

I am getting the below error message :

> System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: Failure sending mail. --->
>   System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server --->
>   System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed
>   because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of
>   time, or established connection failed because connected host has
>   failed to respond

I pinged SMTP host response from this machine and its responding properly. I don't understand why I get this error frequently.

Comment: Team , anyone can help me to resolve this issue.  its working in my machine. if i run the same code in remote machine.  I am getting timeout error sometime i am getting unable to connnect server.

Comment: See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22687211/system-net-mail-smtpexception-failure-sending-mail-from-remote-mail-server

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like firewall to me. Even if ping works, you may have port 25 blocked.  Use telnet to test if the port is open from a DOS command line like this:

```
telnet QAsmtp.company.net 25
```

Comment: thanks team, i raised the ticket for firewall rules to allow the new address. i got it. thanks